# Invertible pseudo random number generator

Tags: random, random-functions

I want to create a random sequence using a given seed. However when given a sequence I also want to calculate the seed which produces the sequence.

Of course this is not possible using a "true" random number generator. But it should be possible using a pseudo random number generator.

As far as I understand I am looking for a deterministic sequence that appears to be random.

Can someone hint me to such a sequence or something similar which produces a nearly random sequence but is invertible?

Comment: The point of many applications of pseudo-random numbers is that they shouldn't be easy to extrapolate from a given portion of the pseudo-random sequence (otherwise adversaries could foil an algorithm/protocol based on assumptions that the pseudo-random numbers are hard to predict). In particular this means that the seed should be "hard" to quickly recover, even given a large portion of the pseudo-random sequence.

Comment: If you restrict your seeds to be a small enough set so that you can generate a handful of pseudo-random numbers with every seed in your restricted set, then you can use a hash table or trie to determine the seed given the first few values of the pseudorandom sequence. But this is brute force basically, by considering all seeds as a preprocessing step. Like I said before, you probably won't be able to find a "common" seed-based PRNG where reverse-engineering the seed Is computationally not bad.

Comment: No I am aiming for a larger sequence so brute force is not an option.

But there are deterministic sequences out there that at least appear to be random. Of course they aren't but pseudo random is more than enough for me.

Comment: Basically the only other thing I can think of is to define your first pseudo-random number to be the seed itself, assuming your seed can fit in the same numerical range etc. as the pseudo-random numbers you are generating. Then if you know the first pseudo-random number in the sequence it's trivial to get the seed.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/predicting-values-from-a-linear-congruential-generator http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10608/how-to-attack-a-fixed-lcg-with-partial-output

Comment: This answer is probably relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743470/is-it-possible-to-reverse-a-pseudo-random-number-generator